# javascript: calling function in for-loop

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

loop that executes a function. However, the following works - the counter counts while the images on the page are loaded.

```
var progress = function()
 {
   for (var i = 0; i < slide.length; i++)
    slide[i].onload = function(){
         actualprogress +=1,
         loading.innerHTML = actualprogress
    };
 }
```

While the following does **not** work. When I open the Page the counter says "[n]" (number of slides, e.g. "12") from the beginning.

```
var progress = function()
 {
   var action = function(){
     actualprogress +=1;
     loading.innerHTML = actualprogress
   }
   for (var i = 0; i < slide.length; i++)
     slide[i].onload = action();
 }
```

I would like to call a function from the for-loop because I will need to do other and more things within the function. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Also think about using indentation

Comment: I did now, sorry about that and thank you for telling me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first code you are assigning the function **pointer** to the onload property.

In the second code you are assigning the function **returned value** to the onload property which is **null**.

There is a huge difference between those. The **parantheses** are **extra** in the **second** code, after **action**.

```
onload = action() => onload = action
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

On the last line of the second snippet, you're calling the function, instead of just assigning it to `slide[i].onload`.

Simply change `slide[i].onload = action();` to `slide[i].onload = action;`.